# What to do with remote branch that has Conflict in the name?

Tags: git

I run `git branch -r` and it lists the following:

```
remotes/origin/release/b1
remotes/origin/release/b1 - Conflict On 2015_09_01 12_58_39
```

In Stash, the branch with "Conflict" in the name does not exist.

What does this "Conflict" branch mean, is it safe to remove, and if so, how?

Comment: Not sure but in Team Foundation Server you can run into conflicts when checking in & merging code into the branch. Did perhaps someone try to modify the branch you are talking about but could not do so because of a conflict that needs to be resolved ?

Comment: It was probably me, but i am 99% sure i fixed/resolved everything way back in September.  What i'm trying to figure out is what to do with this branch name.  Even pruning does not clear it, thus don't want to delete it without knowing what could happen.

Answer (score 2):

This answer has two parts, one generally true and one specific to this branch name.

(part 1)

Remote branch names are normally managed on the remote.  That is, you *can* do this:

```
git branch -r -d "b1 - Conflict On 2015_09_01 12_58_39"
```

to delete it locally, but it will still exist on the remote and you will re-acquire it on the next `git fetch`.

If you have the right permissions, you can do a delete-push operation:

```
git push origin :"Conflict On 2015_09_01 12_58_39"
```

or:

```
git push --delete "Conflict On 2015_09_01 12_58_39"
```

Once it no longer exists on the remote, `git fetch --prune` should delete the local copy.

(part 2)

Spaces are normally not allowed in branch names.  Presumably this branch name was created by a badly-behaved program.  It may be necessary to fix this by logging on to the remote directly; I'm not sure if the normal push-to-delete mechanisms work on these (I would have to cheat and create a bad branch name to test it out).

Comment: thanks @torek, but i can't seem to delete it at all.  when i try the `git branch -r -d "release/b1 - Conflict On 2015_09_01 12_58_39"`, it says remote branch not found, and when i tried the `git push origin :" it complained about  refs.  As it is enterprise stash, i can't log on either.  Assuming it is no harm for it to exist, i guess it can stay there?

Comment: It's certainly "mostly harmless" (just annoying when you see it pop up with some tools, and it may hang on to some commits that would otherwise get garbage-collected).  So it's like the entry for Earth in the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy. :-)